# Avoid using # encoding: UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, unicode, character-encoding

I ran into a problem with a Rails controller where it choked on a Unicode string:

> syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ']'
>   ...conditions => ['url like ?', "%日本%"])

The solution to this problem was to set the encoding at the top of the controller file using

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

Is there any way to set this globally? I keep on getting into trouble by forgetting to set it in files. Alternatively, is there a default somewhere that will make sure that all strings are thought of as Unicode? Are there any problems with setting everything to be Unicode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting environment variable `RUBYOPT` to `-Ku` value:

```
export RUBYOPT="-Ku"
```

Answer (score 4):

In less than a month, Ruby 2.0 will be released, which will have UTF-8 as the default encoding. Then, you will not need to do that any more.